# Can you better explain the feat Fast Learner (Human)?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats

One of the players in a game I am part of wants to take the feat Fast Learner (Human) at level 1. The problem is that both the GM and I can't quite follow the wording of the second part.

> When you gain a level in a favored class, you gain both +1 hit point
> and +1 skill rank instead of choosing either one or the other benefit
> or you can choose an alternate class reward.

From "instead" onwards it gets a bit muddy. Can someone help me understand what the RAW here are saying enough that I can explain it to others?

Answer (score 17):

Normally, when a character gains a level in their [favored class](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/character-advancement/#Favored_Class) they may either choose to gain +1 HP or +1 skill rank. There are also bonus racial bonuses which can replace this bonus. For example, a [Human Monk](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/core-races/human/#Favored_Class_Options) could choose to increase their ki pool by +1/4.

Fast Learner allows you to pick both +1 HP and +1 skill rank. You gain no additional benefit if you select the alternate class bonus.

This interpretation is backed-up by Jason Nelson, the [feat's author](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2p3m4&page=2?Fast-Learner#51), and [Stephen Radney-MacFarland](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2qdnd?Fast-Learner-What-exactly-are-our-options#49), one of the designer's behind the *Advanced Race Guide* where Fast Learner was published.

Comment: While probably the most accurate interpretation of the text, the fact that the text _is_ muddled and this interpretation cannot be certain should be a part of the answer. (And, at least IMO, so should the fact that this is a dumb rule and should be ignored.)

Comment: The feat's author literally says that he can't address the intention behind this feat: "I can't really address the RAI on that one, as the rules text for the Fast Learner feat is different from what I sent in." and that he is unsure of how to interpret it, saying it's a mere guess: "but your guess is as good as mine".

How can that "back up" something that is unclear to the author himself?

Answer (score 2):

The [Fast Learner](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Fast%20Learner) feat is indeed written poorly, as it takes a lot of effort to understand it properly. This also results in some controversy, but it can be understood through proper partitioning and sequential reading of the sentence.

### Trigger

> **Benefit:** When you gain a level in a favored class, ...

The benefit of this feat is triggered upon gaining a level in a favored class. The rest of the sentence defines which benefit is gained from the feat.

Important to note here is that it does **not** say that the bonus is **retroactive**, so it pays off to take this feat as soon as possible, as you won't get any benefits from the feat for levels you already have in your favored class.

### Normal Options

As for the benefits given, let's first see what happens usually (i.e. without the feat) upon gaining a level in a favored class:

> [Favored Class](https://www.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Favored%20Class&Category=Character%20Advancement) (Core Rulebook p.31): [...] Whenever a character gains a level in his favored class, he receives either + 1 hit point or + 1 skill rank. [...]

> [Racial Favored Class Bonus](https://www.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Racial%20Favored%20Class%20Bonus&Category=Favored%20Class) (Advanced Player's Guide p.8): [...] As in the previous section, what is presented here is a set of alternative benefits that characters of each race may choose instead of the normal benefits for their favored class. [...]

So usually a character has 3 options when gaining a favored class level:

1. [Usual Option #1]: +1 hit point
2. [Usual Option #2]: +1 skill rank
3. [Usual Option #3]: alternate (racial) class reward

*Usual Option #3* (from the *Advanced Player's Guide*) is RAW a replacement for *Usual Options #1 & #2* (from the *Core Rulebook*).

Note: The **Fast Learner** feat refers to *Usual Option #3* when it speaks of *"an alternate class reward"*.

### Feat Options

After that is settled, let's break the benefit part of the feat's sentence into its two main parts first:

> [Part 1] you gain both +1 hit point and +1 skill rank instead of choosing either one or the other benefit

> [Part 2] or you can choose an alternate class reward.

---

Just for summary, let's re-write the whole sentence of the feat with just one part each (with parentheses for the replacement in Part 1):

> When you gain a level in a favored class, you gain both +1 hit point and +1 skill rank (instead of choosing either one or the other benefit).

OR

> When you gain a level in a favored class, you can choose an alternate class reward.

---

**Part 1** of the feat benefit gives us the option to take *"both +1 hit point AND +1 skill rank"*.

But if we take this option then we don't get to choose a usual favored class bonus, because it requires us to replace *Usual Option #1 & #2* with the feat's option: *"instead of choosing either one or the other benefit"*.

The *"either one or the other benefit"* refers to Usual Option #1 & Usual Option #2 respectively.

Thus, the feat allows you to **replace** your usual favored class reward with the option to get both +1 hit point AND +1 skill rank.

---

**Part 2** of the feat benefit is pretty straightforward:
It allows you to take an alternate (racial) favored class reward. Unlike Part 1 it doesn't require you to sacrifice your usual favored class reward either.

So after taking your usual class reward (i.e. Usual Options #1, #2, or #3), you can take the alternate class reward (i.e. Usual Option #3 can be taken).

---

### TL;DR

Anyone who has this feat and gains a level in a favored class has the following four options:

- +1 hit point AND +1 skill rank [Feat Option #1; usual options are replaced]
- +1 hit point [Usual Option #1] and an alternate class reward [Feat Option #2]
- +1 skill rank [Usual Option #2] and an alternate class reward [Feat Option #2]
- gain an alternate class reward [Usual Option #3] and gain an alternate class reward [Feat Option #2]

---

### Edit: Grammar Nazi

(Edit to clarify the proper understanding and resolving grammar issues)

The many conjunctions ("and", "or") in the sentence of the Fast Learner feat make it necessary to go a little more in-depth into how they work. As the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/conjunctions) explains, *"and, but, either … or"* are so-called *"coordinating conjunctions"*, which *"connect items which are the same grammatical type, e.g. words, phrases, clauses."*

It's also helpful to look over the examples of connections given by the Cambridge Dictionary.

And although [the preposition "instead of"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/de/worterbuch/englisch/instead-of), could function as a conjunction, prepositions only do so when followed by a clause, but not when followed by a noun phrase.

So let's look at the feat again, where I will mark all the conjunctions **in bold** (until addressed), to decide which parts of the sentence are linked by them:

> you gain both +1 hit point **and** +1 skill rank instead of choosing **either** one **or** the other benefit **or** you can choose an alternate class reward.

The first **"and"** is linking the two phrases *"+1 hit point"* & *"+1 skill rank"*. This part is rarely misunderstood, since both phrases are adjacent to this one-word-conjunction and another interpretation is grammatically impossible.

> you gain both [+1 hit point]-and-[+1 skill rank] instead of choosing **either** one **or** the other benefit **or** you can choose an alternate class reward.

The first really poor part of the sentence structure appears here, as this *"either"*'s connection to the following *"or"* (to form "either...or") can only be understood later, once *"the other benefit"* appears. This is to say, the sentence could be perfectly read as *"you gain both +1 hit point and +1 skill rank instead of choosing either one"*, and the following "or" could be seen as connecting another clause.

However, once "the other benefit" appears behind this "or", the "either" can no longer be understood as one-word-conjunction and works grammatically as the two-part-conjunction "either...or", as it is followed by a phrase. The one-word-conjunction would have to be followed by a clause. (see the [examples in the Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/conjunctions) again)

Thus, "either... or" and the following phrase are one part of the sentence:

> you gain both +1 hit point and +1 skill rank instead of [choosing either one or the other benefit] **or** you can choose an alternate class reward.

The last "or" in the sentence cannot be part of this "either...or" construction, as that last "or" is followed by a clause, not a phrase.

---

This **difference between clause and phrase** is also the key to understanding the final part of this sentence, because *"coordinating conjunctions connect items which are **the same grammatical type**, e.g. words, phrases, clauses."* ([CD](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/conjunctions))

Examples:

1. "You can have a green apple OR a red apple."
2. "You can have a green apple OR you can have a red apple."

Example #1 is 1 sentence with 1 clause, that contains 2 phrases ("a green apple" & "a red apple"), and these 2 phrases are linked with "OR".
Example #2 is 1 sentence with 2 clauses ("you can have a green apple" & "you can have a red apple"), that each contain 1 phrase, and these 2 clauses are linked with "OR".

I'll mark the phrases in (parentheses) and the clauses in [brackets].

This can be tested by switching the order of things without violating grammar rules:

1. "You can have (a green apple) OR (a red apple)."

-> "You can have (a red apple) OR (a green apple)."

2. "[You can have a green apple] OR [you can have a red apple]."

-> "[you can have a red apple] OR [You can have a green apple]."

However, when you try to switch a clause with a phrase, you'd violate grammar:

1. "[You can have a green apple] OR (a red apple)."

-> "(a red apple) OR [You can have a green apple]."

We see that we need to leave the *"You can have"* where it is, and that only the "a green apple" and "a red apple" can switch places. Thus the "OR" only links "a green apple" and "a red apple".

The same happens either way for example #2:

2. "You can have (a green apple) OR [you can have a red apple]."

-> "You can have [you can have a red apple] OR (a green apple)."

2. "[You can have a green apple] OR you can have (a red apple)."

-> "(a red apple) OR you can have [You can have a green apple]."

---

Moving on from the examples, back to the feat:

> you gain both +1 hit point and +1 skill rank instead of choosing either one or the other benefit **or** you can choose an alternate class reward.

Let's mark the clauses:

> [you gain both +1 hit point and +1 skill rank instead of choosing either one or the other benefit] **or** [you can choose an alternate class reward].

There are many phrases in there (so not marking them all), but the two clauses are easy to spot, because a (non-imperative) clause always contains a subject and a verb: "you gain" and "you can". As no other part of the sentence has subject + verb, these other parts cannot be clauses.

This is the thought process that leads to the final conclusion, that the last "or" links these two distinct parts:

> you gain both +1 hit point and +1 skill rank instead of choosing either one or the other benefit

OR

> you can choose an alternate class reward.

It is grammatically impossible to think otherwise, because after the "or" is an entire **clause** [you can ...], and the only other **clause** in this sentence is the entire [you gain ... the other benefit].

This is why the formal representation for the statements with A, B, C (or similar logical symbols) leads to misunderstandings: The "A and B or C" representation is **illegal**, for A, B, and C are different grammatical types here! A and B represent **phrases**, while C is a **clause**.

As a final example, you would have to remove the following words to turn the second clause into a phrase:

> you gain both +1 hit point and +1 skill rank instead of choosing either one or the other benefit or <s>you can choose</s> an alternate class reward.

This C="an alternate class reward" would be a phrase, and could then be legally compared to the first two statements A and B. But we are given a C="you can choose an alternate class reward", which is a clause and thus of a different type than A & B.

For ease of reading, here is the feat split into 2 distinct sentences, each containing just 1 of the 2 clauses (instead of combining these 2 clauses into 1 sentence):

> **Benefit:** When you gain a level in a favored class, you gain both +1 hit point and +1 skill rank (instead of choosing either one or the other benefit).
>
> OR
>
> **Benefit:** When you gain a level in a favored class, you can choose an alternate class reward.

---

### RAW or RAI?

> Can someone help me understand what the RAW here are saying enough that I can explain it to others?

The OP asks what the RAW ("Rules As Written") of this feat is, not the RAI ("Rules As Intended"). That should be the focus of any answer here.

Also, I support this preference of RAW over RAI for the following reason (that anyone who works in a publishing company is aware of):

A book is created by **many** people, and passes through many hands before the final release. Thus there are many different intentions behind the rules texts, and more often than not these intentions differ. This is made abundantly clear in this case by [Jason Nelson, the author of this feat](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2p3m4&page=2?Fast-Learner#51):

> I can't really address the RAI on that one, as the rules text for the Fast Learner feat is different from what I sent in.

So to be clear, not even the author himself knows the RAI behind this feat. This also means that the author and [the designer didn't work the feat out together](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2qdnd?Fast-Learner-What-exactly-are-our-options#49).

We also don't know who else made any changes to the feat's rules text before the final release. This is why trying to surmise the RAI is usually a futile attempt (unless it's spelling errors, cut/copy-and-paste mistakes, or formatting errors). Furthermore (from personal experience), people sometimes also forget what their original intent really was when you ask them a few years later, making it nigh impossible to discover the RAI even if you can talk to everyone involved.

As a reader you are only left with the rules as written. That is one of the reasons why RPG publishing companies like Paizo or WotC always have a **FAQ** section, or something similar where official rule clarifications are posted. Before something is released as a FAQ, it usually goes through the same (or very similar) review process as when published in a book. Thus, many eyes take a look at it, reducing the chance of making mistakes, and in RPG companies you usually have the entire rules design team involved in the FAQ process. That is why companies frequently caution against making/following statements by single authors, designers, or reviewers, as these views are fundamentally incomplete. This is similar to the process of a news article by a journalist undergoing review by one or more editors before being published.

This feat's clashing intentions and poor wording has thus spawned discussions with several hundreds of comments - just in the Paizo forums [here](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2p3m4?Fast-Learner) and [here](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2qdnd?Fast-Learner-What-exactly-are-our-options) - without the designer seeing himself at any fault in this.

However, a strict reading RAW and with proper English grammar comes only to the conclusions laid out in this comment and [this one from a Paizo forum user 10 years ago](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2p3m4?Fast-Learner#29).

### Two alternate class rewards?

Yes, that's possible, because one of these is the usual favored class reward (which remains untouched) and the other one is the benefit of the Fast Learner feat. Here the feat's text again [split into two distinct sentences as described above]:

> **Benefit:** When you gain a level in a favored class, you gain both +1 hit point and +1 skill rank instead of choosing either one or the other benefit.
>
> OR
>
> **Benefit:** When you gain a level in a favored class, you can choose an alternate class reward.

It's weird to think that choosing option 2 somehow removes your usual favored class reward, as there is absolutely nothing in the feat that indicates this. It would neither make sense grammatically (as you can't move prepositions freely between clauses), nor semantically: Where would the feat's "**Benefit**" be in choosing that option?

### TL;DR

Anyone who has this feat and gains a level in a favored class has the following four options:

- +1 hit point AND +1 skill rank [Feat Option #1; usual options are replaced]
- +1 hit point [Usual Option #1] and an alternate class reward [Feat Option #2]
- +1 skill rank [Usual Option #2] and an alternate class reward [Feat Option #2]
- gain an alternate class reward [Usual Option #3] and gain an alternate class reward [Feat Option #2]

---

Comment: I agree that the feat says "You can get A and B instead of just A or just B, or you can take C" but, as C was already one of the options, I would say that you're taking C as you already could, not in addition to your usual choice.

Comment: @Zachiel Yeah, I'm just not seeing how anything leads to the possibility of the TL;DR's 3rd and 4th bullets. I mean, the original says that "you gain both +1 hit point and +1 skill rank… **or** you can choose an alternate class reward" (emphasis mine). I don't know how to read that so that Part 2 "doesn't require you to sacrifice your usual favored class reward." Seriously, someone says, "You can have both a burger and fries or a taco," you can't have a burger and a taco, and you can't have fries and a taco. (Yes, that's a pretty terrible feat, but there are lots of terrible feats.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan I know how to read it that way, and it's the Theoretical Optimization gotcha: "you didn't say I can get the taco _instead_ of the normal benefits, so _of course_ it must mean I get it in addition.". It's just very clearly a TO gotcha.

Comment: Also note how, by a different clever reading, the DM can say that yes, you can _choose_ an alternate class reward, but nowhere it is said that you _get_ it.

Comment: @Zachiel I remember a conversation years ago on this site with a user who advocated the word *only* precede any exclusive choice. For instance, "Pick only A or only B" instead of "Pick A or B." The user claimed that without *only*, picking either meant the other was still available to be picked, essentially redefining *or* to mean *and/or* if it doesn't say *or only*. Is this answer just a continuation of that idea? Is that a formal logic thing? A programming thing? Because it's not a grammar-in-English thing.

Comment: In casual speech, when you say "take A and B or C" you would use intonation to say, for example, "take A and B, ...oooor C" to make the the alternatives more distinct. However, in written form, there's no such way, except for using more words and/or punctation characters. While 'and' is always clear (almost), the 'or' makes it often hard to build a precise unambiguous sentence. 'Only' has a different semantics and adds unintented meaning sometimes. That's why I prefer to add "either". "Pick either A and B, or C", and now it would be way more clear.

Comment: However, with the words as they are, in cases when it's just `You can have both a burger and fries or a taco`, it's totally unclear. It could be either `You can have both (a burger and fries) or (a taco)`, or `You can have both (a burger) and (fries or a taco)`. Sure, you could argue that one way is more natural and no people say it the other way, but I can assure you, I've been there many times, and there are LOTS of people that DO say it the other way. Regardless of which is the way, and which is the other one. It's spoken. It's not math. The rule should get an errata from the author.

Comment: To support my take on this, let me just add that when I've read this for the first time, I understood it as this: `When you gain a level in a favored class, you gain ((both +1 hit point and +1 skill rank) instead of (choosing either one)) or (the other benefit) or (you can choose an alternate class reward).` and I couldn't figure out what is that `other benefit`. Notice that the "other benefit" is in the same or-level as the "alternate reward"..  I've had to read it several times to notice that the author probably intended "(choosing (either one or the other) benefit)". It's awful wording IMHO

Comment: @HeyICanChan that's _inclusive or_ and it is very much English. "A triangle can be defined as a polygon with thre sides or as a polygon with three vertices."

Comment: @Zachiel That's totally fair, but contextually that's also not the case here. *Pick A **or** B* really doesn't entitle you to pick A **and** B.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Oh, no, that's not what is going on here. Normally, without the feat, you have "pick A or B" and then the option to pick neither and pick C instead. Then the feat gives you the chance to pick "A and B" instead of A or instead of B, and the chance to pick C. But it doesn't say that to pick C you have to renounce to anything you could have had normally, without the feat. So you get your choice to pick A or B or C as usual and on top of that you choose the option from the feat that's outside of the "instead" clause, getting a new instance of C on top of whataver you chose.

Comment: @Zachiel The replacement only replaces the A-or-B part, and leaves "or C", that's true, but at best, you get a change from `pick (pick(get A), or pick (get B)), or pick (get C)`, into `pick (pick(get A+B), or pick (get C)), or pick (get C)`. That's because in the replacement rule, there's no A-and-B-and-C, but rather, it's repeated A+B or C, just like in the original rule. So, you end up effectively with `pick(get A+B), or pick(get C), or pick(get C)` which doesn't give you the change to get two C in any way. You just git two options that give you the same outcome.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl that's also how I choose to read it, but I was explaining there's actually a reading where you get a change from `pick (pick(get A), or pick (get B)), or pick (get C)` to `pick (pick(get A+B)) instead of the previous, or pick (get C) in addition to the previous` In addition is unstated, and that's what Theaitetos is going with, because bad wording leaves space for that. I'm just saying it's RAW but it's so weird that there's no way it's right.